# Cannot connect to phone after upgrading the firm ware

Tags: android, firmware

I am developing on Windows 7 platform using my HTC HERO.

The original firmware is 1.5. I've heard that 2.2 is new and is faster than 1.5, so I updated the firmware to 2.2. (There are quiet a few concepts here, like SPL, Recovery, ROM, Radio) I think I only upgraded ROM.

The phone works fine. However, my windows 7 cannot find the device anymore. Also `adb devices` cannot find the device either.

(I didn't backup my old ROM, and I've tried to flash a few 2.2 ROMs available online, none of them could be found by Windows 7.)

Can anyone give me some hint on solving this problem. Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

I try to find the official ROM. E.g. http://www.htc.com/uk/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=671&news_id=254. But when I input my SN number, it says that this update does not work for my phone. It seems that there are a lot of HEROs there and I don't know which HERO is my phone.

In Windows 7, the system can find the device, but says that cannot install the driver correctly.

When I press BACK + Power Off key, I can enter recover mode and Windows can connects to the phone correctly. And also `adb devices` displays:

```
D:\android\android-sdk-windows-old\tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
HT9BJL904379    recovery
```

[image]

USB VID:

[image]

**Finally** I am done! Thanks for @Chris Stratton's hint!
I use the solution here:

http://alt236.blogspot.com/2010/09/adb-will-not-detect-phone-after-rom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed an unofficial rom, perhaps it changes the usb VID/PID meaning you need a new driver.  You should ask the authors of your unofficial rom which driver to use for that rom on windows 7.  If you were using an OEM driver, perhaps you now need the vanilla SDK one.

Also look in the device manager (or boot from a linux CD or something) and see if plugging in the phone results in an additional unknown USB device showing up.

Ideally you'd use another computer with a more user-friendly operating system to verify that the phone's usb interface is working after the upgrade - it's also possibly that something isn't right with your unofficial upgrade and you don't in fact have a working USB/ADB interface on the phone right now.

Did you re-enable USB debugging in the settings menu after the upgrade?

Comment: +1. Thanks for your info! I updated my question based on your advice.

Comment: The recovery system is an entirely separate mini-install of firmware, so being able to adb into that only indicates the hardware isn't broken.  You say you can't get the official install, so apparently you are using an unofficial one.  You need to determine if it's showing up as an unkown VID/PID and find a driver that supports that, or ask the people who wrote this ROM what driver you need.  It wouldn't hurt to also try the vanilla android SDK usb driver if you were previously using an HTC or carrier-supplied one.  Can you try a machine with a more mature operating system?

Comment: The USB driver I was using for the old firmware is the vanilla SDK one. I will find a linux box and work on that..

Comment: Probably the key thing right now is to figure out how you can see the USB VID/PID of connected devices.  If you boot from a live linux CD, this would be dmesg or lsusb, but you can probably do it from windows device manager.  Also did you check that you enabled usb debugging in settings after the upgrade, and selected any appropriate options from the USB status bar notification drop down?

Comment: Sure. I enabled debugging on the phone.

Comment: You need to click through the tabs to find the VID/PID

Comment: Thanks! I've found it. Please see the updated picture. What shall I do next?

Comment: You google it.  Or you could just go to http://alt236.blogspot.com/2010/09/adb-will-not-detect-phone-after-rom.html    Basically they are telling you to change the .inf file (probably android_winusb.inf) for the driver to add a block with your new numbers.  Significantly, their numbers are the same as the ones you just found.